# Load JFIF - Jpeg image in reactsjs

Tags: reactjs, jpeg, jfif

Im trying to get Microsoft photo using

The following API

#Get
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/photo/$value

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/profilephoto-get?view=graph-rest-1.0

but the response im getting the picture in encoded as JFIF

����\u0000\u0010JFIF\u0000\u0001\u0001\u0001\u0000`\u00

[image]

Any suggestion how I could load the image as JPEG

Comment: try to play with the content type in your header -> you can set it to JPEG

Comment: See if this helps: https://simplernerd.com/js-image-binary-jfif/